# Vuejs add css class to ul li list from array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have someting like this array:

```
items : [
   {
      cssClass : 'item1'
      text : 'some text 1'
   }

   {
      cssClass : 'item2'
      text : 'some text 2'
   }
]
```

i want make li that will have this cssClass class name

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in items" class="{{item.className}}">{{item.text}}</li> 
</ul>
```

i need this type output

```
<ul>
    <li class="item1">some text 1</li>
    <li class="item2">some text 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind key dynamically you can do like this

```
 <li v-for="item in items" :class="{[item.cssClass] : true}">{{item.text}}</li>
```

Or

```
  <li v-for="item in items" :class="item.cssClass">{{item.text}}</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply do

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in items" :class="item.cssClass">{{item.text}}</li> 
</ul>
```

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mananvaghasiya/1ycvwwrb/4/ feel free to inspect list items to see the class name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use directive [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) for this:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in items" v-bind:class="item.className">{{item.text}}</li> 
</ul>
```

or in short:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in items" :class="item.className">{{item.text}}</li> 
</ul>
```